# Regular Expression and Capture Groups

Tags: java, regex

I have a question regarding Java regular expressions and capture groups. My goal is to parse a log file and extract relevant fields into QRadar. I am not exactly writing Java code however since QRadar uses Java regular expressions to parse the log file and since my question is a regular expression problem I am posting it here in hope of getting some pointers/solution to my problem.

Here goes my question -

I am trying to parse a log file that is a CEF (Common Event Format) formatted log file. Following are a couple of lines from the log file -

```
[blah, blah...] cs1=DataValue1 cs2=DataValue2

[blah, blah...] cs2=DataValue3 cs1=DataValue4
```

My goal is to extract the data values for the fields `cs1` and `cs2` from the above lines. So I am interested in capturing the values - `DataValue1`, `DataValue2`, `DataValue3` and `DataValue4` from the above lines

I came up with the following regular expressions for accomplishing the same -

RegEx for cs1 field - `\scs1\=(.*?)\s\w+\=`

RegEx for cs2 field - `\scs2\=(.*?)\s\w+\=`

Using the above regular expressions and capture group I am able to capture the data values. But only in certain cases. So if you look at the log entries above you will notice that the order of the fields `cs1` and `cs2` within the log entry is not fixed. So at times the `cs1` field appears before `cs2` (in the middle of log entry) and at other times the field `cs1` appears at the end (is the last field) of the log entry. Similar behavior exists with `cs2` field as well. Using my current regular expression only works when the field is not the last field.

E.g. for the 1st log entry line  `[blah, blah...] cs1=DataValue1 cs2=DataValue2`, my regular expressions correctly parse/extract the value of the `cs1` field but they fail for the `cs2` field since `cs2` field is at the end of the line.

Similarly, for the 2nd log entry line `[blah, blah...] cs2=DataValue3 cs1=DataValue4`, my regular expressions correctly parse/extract the value of `cs2` field but they fail to extract the value for the `cs1` field since `cs1` field is at the end of the line.

My question is - What should my regular expression be so that it can parse/extract the data field value correctly irrespective of whether the field appears in the middle or at the end of the log file entry?

Any help is appreciated

Regards,

P.S.: In case anyone is interested I posted this question on the QRadar forum as well (https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=f48bc2dc-2ccb-42df-b543-dc0522491fad) but no luck yet with any responses...

Comment: This site seems to describe the format of the CEF file: http://www.iwebdev.it/blog/?tag=common-event-format Don't use catch all `.*?` and expect the file to be parsed correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a lookahead to capture the values of `cs1` and `cs2` fields, if you don't know the order of it's arrangement.

```
^(?=.*?\scs1=(\S+))(?=.*\scs2=(\S+))
```

Java regex would be,

```
^(?=.*?\\scs1=(\\S+))(?=.*\\scs2=(\\S+))
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/jC4qF9/3)

Group index 1 contains the value of `cs1` and index 2 contains the value of `cs2`

Comment: This is only a partially working solution for 98-99% of the cases, and fails for the rest 1-2%.

Comment: Thanks Avinash. I think that helps me quite a bit. However, the problem I am stuck with now is that is the values can have the `space` character in it. So legitimate values could be `Data Value 1` and so on. I think in your current regular expressions the `\S` basically stops at the whitespace character and captures only part of the value. I am trying to tweak your regular expression so that it accounts for that. No luck yet. In case you are able to tweak your reg ex to take into account the 'space' character then please add the updated regular expression here...

Comment: could you post a sample string which reflects the above?

Comment: Got it working. I used the following RegEx's to parse the values for the fields `cs1` and `cs2`  respectively -  `\scs1\=(.*?)(?:(?:\s\w+\=)|(?:\n))` and `\scs2\=(.*?)(?:(?:\s\w+\=)|(?:\n))`. This parses the following sample data strings fine - `[blah, blah...] cs1=Data Value 1 cs2=Data Value 2` and `[blah, blah...] cs2=Data Value 3 cs1=Data Value 4`

Comment: yeah just posted the sample and the reg ex i used...I hit Enter/Return a bit early and hence only got half of my comment...I edited my previous comment to include the sample as well as the regex I used...

Comment: you don't need a two non-capturing groups. Just `\scs1\=(.*?)(?:\s\w+\=|\n)` would be enough.